# Why do development and production modes lead to different web pages?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I try the latest [Play Framework 2.3.7](https://www.playframework.com/) on Mac OS Yosemite, then I followed the tutorial to create web page

```
$ activator new my-first-app play-scala
$ cd my-first-app
$ activator run
```

It's generated a nice looking page with colors and many contents and a header like this:

[image]

Then I type `Ctrl+D` to close this application, and use the production mode:

```
$ activator start
```

It only generates a plain text web with only the header like this:

[image]

What should I do to show all the other stuffs in the production mode?

Comment: Where are your resources located? If they are located under the public folder, you should use reverse routing in order to make them accessible. It seems that your css is not being loaded.

Comment: @BrunoFollon, I think the css file is in the public folder because the commands I listed are the only ones I typed. But I don't understand the reverse routing you mentioned. Is there a simple way to load the needed resources in the production mode?

Comment: This might help you understand how assets work in the play framework: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets

Answer (score 6):

That's expected. The Play welcome page helper includes a stack of things, including links to the full locally served documentation and stylesheets/images/etc, that are (rightly) turned off in prod mode. So in prod mode, because all that stuff that the welcome page needs is turned off, the welcome page instead renders an unstyled one liner, as you can see.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I tried to turn on the stuff, but after I read how assets work as mentioned in this question comments, I still failed to show the whole page in prod page, it's really frustrating. Could you please tell me how to turn all the stuff on?

Comment: Nothing that you need is turned off! Only serving the documentation, which the welcome page heavily relies on. When you do deploy your site, do you want someone using it to read the play documentation? Of course not! So the play documentation stylesheets and images, which you have no need for outside of dev mode, are disabled. Your own stylesheets and images will continue to work with no problems.

Comment: I want to know how to configure so that I know which files to be loaded in prod mode. Otherwise even if I change the play documentation and add my "own" contents in the same file, it still won't show in the prod mode.

Comment: Put your static resources in the public directory. Seriously, start actually writing a real app and stop getting worried over the Play welcome page... You'll find there is absolutely nothing missing or different.